Next.js TypeScript form handling with server action in Nextjs - Error: e._formData.get is not a function
I'm trying to handle form submission in a Next.js 14 server action, using TypeScript in a project. I'm using FormData to gather form data and I'm encountering an error: Error: e._formData.get is not a function.
Here's my code:
export default async function PageDashboard() {
  async function handleAuth(formData: FormData) {
    "use server";

    const data = {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
    };

    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <form className="space-y-6" action={handleAuth}>
      <input name="email" placeholder="Email" className="border" />
      <input name="password" placeholder="Password" className="border" />
      <button name="submit" type="submit" className="border">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}



I've tried using FormData in the handleAuth function to get the email and password from the form data, but I'm getting the mentioned error.
How can I correctly handle form submission with FormData in a Next.js project using TypeScript?

handleAuth gets passed the submit event. to get the formdata you can grab it from the event target. You can try this:
export default function PageDashboard() {
  async function handleAuth(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission behavior

    const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);

    const data = {
      email: formData.get("email"),
      password: formData.get("password"),
    };

    console.log(data);
  }

  return (
    <form className="space-y-6" onSubmit={handleAuth}>
      <input name="email" placeholder="Email" className="border" />
      <input name="password" placeholder="Password" className="border" />
      <button type="submit" className="border">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

